# Spring security Authentication parameter in @Controller handler method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the a spring boot method app, and one method has the following singature:

```
@GetMapping("{accountId}/component/{id}")
public Component getComponent(@PathVariable("accountId") String accountId, @PathVariable("id") String id, Authentication auth) throws Exception {
    //
}
```

I understand all parameters except the last parameter : Authentication auth. Where/how does it get passed into the method?

Comment: Is that `Authentication` the Spring one from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html?

Comment: Yes. The org.springframework.security.core.

Comment: Spring MVC understands `javax.security.Principal`, of which `Authentication` is a subclass.